# Hyperlinks in custom list of ... via tocloft

Tags: tocloft

I have a custom command `\todo{<comment>}` which adds a TODO comment in place, which is then added to `List of TODOs` as a line. This is done via `tocloft`.

The only missing part is using hyperlinks in the "List of TODOs" to individual comments. I tried to use a combination of `hypertarget` and `hyperlink` (currently commented in the MWE) but for some reason compiling the MWE takes infinite time on Overleaf.

The MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
    \urlstyle{bfseries}
% \usepackage{calc}      % for \widthof{my text}} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcommand{\listoftodos}{List of TODOs}
\newlistof{todo}{tdo}{\listoftodos}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{todo}
    \textbf{\textsl{TODO: #1}}
    \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{\color{red} \numberline{#1}}\par}
    % \hypertarget{tdo:todo\thetodo}{TODO: #1}
    % \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{\color{red} \hyperlink{tdo:todo\thetodo}{\numberline{#1}}}\par}
\renewcommand\cfttdotitlefont{\color{red}\Huge\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\listoftodo \clearpage

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\todo{Still need something here}

\lipsum[2][1-5]

\lipsum[3][1-3]
\todo{Good explanation but missing an example}

\lipsum[4][1-3]
\todo{Bad explanation! Need rewording}

\todo{Need more paragraphs on theory X}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No need  for `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`. Just add the option `linktocpage` to the argument of `\hypersetup` and recompile twice.

Comment: the link is there but the link area is rather small. Try `\addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{{\color{red}#1}}}`

Comment: @Mico thanks for the clue. I found a similar option `linktoc=all` and it seems to make both text and page hyperlinks, exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The text was over the dots, which I didn't even see until hyperlinks were added. It's based on an example from `tocloft` manual, which uses `\numberlink`, which I don't know what it is for. Everything is working now! Thanks